# perl 64 bit ints under the hood

Tags: perl, integer, 64-bit

I'm confused regarding the internal representation of 64 bit ints in perl.

Ubuntu 12.04, perl 5.16.0:

```
print 18440000000000001000 . "\n";
print 18450000000000001000 . "\n";
print -9220000000000001000 . "\n";
print -9230000000000001000 . "\n";
```

output:

```
18440000000000001000
1.845e+19
-9220000000000001000
-9.23e+18
```

Obviously positive numbers overflow and are coerced to floats, with corresponding loss of precision, at 2^64. However - that leaves no space for a sign bit, so how are the negative numbers up to -2^63 represented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl numbers are represented as either an `IV` or a `UV`. It's a flag on the `SV` structure itself.

I'm guessing when a number becomes signed, the `UV` becomes an `IV`, and vice versa.

Specifically, looking in the SV definition:

```
#define _SV_HEAD_UNION \
union {                             \
    char*   svu_pv;         /* pointer to malloced string */        \
    IV      svu_iv;                 \
    UV      svu_uv;                 \
    SV*     svu_rv;         /* pointer to another SV */             \
    SV**    svu_array;              \
    HE**    svu_hash;               \
    GP*     svu_gp;                 \
    PerlIO *svu_fp;                 \
}   sv_u
```

The `SvIOK` and `SvUOK` flags can be used to see what the actual valid field of the `SV` is.

Comment: Translating slightly for people who aren't familiar with perl internals: a numeric scalar on a 64-bit perl can be a signed *or* unsigned 64-bit int, and perl will convert between them, making the right choice pretty much all the time. That means you can easily work with numbers between -2^63 and +2^64, and the consequence of going outside this range is "only" that you will degrade to floating-point.

Comment: "64-bit perl" includes most perls on 64-bit systems, and perls on 32-bit systems with `ivsize=8`, but not ones with `ivsize=4`. On those perls, `IV`s are signed 32-bit and `UV`s are unsigned 32-bit, but double-precision floating point provides integer accuracy out to +/- 2^53 for `NV`s.